# Chart.js y axis labels are truncated

Tags: chart.js

I have a bootstrap modal where I have a chart.js in it.

The problem is that left Y axis values are truncated.

[image]

This is the HTML in the inspector:

```
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-center">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header" style="background-color:#62a8ea;">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                    </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" style="color:white;">Reading Details</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body" style="height: 400px;"><div><div class="chartjs-size-monitor" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; overflow: hidden; pointer-events: none; visibility: hidden; z-index: -1;"><div class="chartjs-size-monitor-expand" style="position:absolute;left:0;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;overflow:hidden;pointer-events:none;visibility:hidden;z-index:-1;"><div style="position:absolute;width:1000000px;height:1000000px;left:0;top:0"></div></div><div class="chartjs-size-monitor-shrink" style="position:absolute;left:0;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;overflow:hidden;pointer-events:none;visibility:hidden;z-index:-1;"><div style="position:absolute;width:200%;height:200%;left:0; top:0"></div></div></div>
    <canvas id="detail-chart" width="560" height="280" class="chartjs-render-monitor" style="display: block; width: 560px; height: 280px;"></canvas>
</div>
</div>
                <div class="modal-footer">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

> Any clue?

Answer (score 4):

Just add the following:

```
options: {
                                layout: {
                                    padding: {
                                        // Any unspecified dimensions are assumed to be 0
                                        left: 10,
                                        bottom: 5
                                    }
                                },
```

That will fix the problem.

Comment: Hi @VAAA. Your solution doesn't seem to help. Your solution will only shift graph to left by 10px. We want to manage the label in the space available. Suppose the width is of 50px for y-axis.

Answer (score 0):

just copy and paste the below option this will fix your problem and also customize by removing or adding properties.

```
lineGraphOption: ChartOptions = {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    elements: {
        point:
        {
            radius: 0,
        },
    },
    tooltips: {
        mode: 'index'
    },
    layout: {
        padding: {
            top: 50,
            right: 10,
            bottom: 50,
            left: 10,
        }
    },
    legend: {
        position: "bottom",
        display: true,
        onClick: (() => {
        }),
        align: "center",
        labels: {
            boxWidth: 12,
            padding: 30
        },
    },
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            type: 'time',
            time: {
                unit: 'day',
                minUnit: 'month',

                unitStepSize: 4,
                displayFormats: {
                    'month': 'MMM DD',
                }
            },
            ticks: {
                max: '31 Oct',
            }
        }],
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                callback: function (value) {
                    return value + ' K'
                }
            },
        }]
    },

    plugins: {

    }
}
```