# Chart JS Custom Labels don't work

Tags: javascript, chart.js, truncate

I am trying to truncate the labels on my horizontal bar chart but can't seem to get the callback to actually work.

```
yAxes: [{
        maxBarThickness: 50,
        gridLines: false,
        ticks: {
          padding: 10,
          callback: value => {
            let new_label = null;
            if (value.length > 15) {
              new_label = value.substring(0, 15) + '...';
            } else {
              new_label = value;
            }
            return new_label;
          },
        },
      }],
```

Comment: What's the larger context? Where is that "yAxes" property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use below option of changing value to string using toString() and then just return value bases on length

```
callback: value => {
                if (value.toString().length > 15) {
                 return value.toString().substr(0, 15) + '...'; //truncate
                   } else {
                 return value
                }
              }
```

code example for reference - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/zaLVeO

**Note**: Check the padding values in the options, check this link for more details - [Chart.js y axis labels are truncated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47681315/chart-js-y-axis-labels-are-truncated)  incase of missing truncated values due to padding

Comment: Awesome! I didn’t even think of that being an issue, thank you!

Comment: Glad it worked for you :) , please mark my post as answer , if it helped to resolve your issue